# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityError: "InvalidUserName"

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I did default Megration with User model, added only my two custom properties. EF created standard flow of tables.

[image]

And my AspNetUsers table

[image]

As you can see UserName can be null.

My User Model

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string CreateAt { get; set; }
    public User()
    {
        this.CreateAt = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now);
    }
}
```

And when I create user, I have exeption

[image]

But I didnt make any validation or rules for UserName.
My startup configuration for ApplicationDBContext

```
services.AddIdentityCore<User>(opts =>
        {
            opts.Password.RequiredLength = 5;
            opts.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            opts.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
            opts.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
            opts.Password.RequireDigit = true; 
            opts.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = null;
        }).AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDBContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

`opts.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = null;` Didn't help me. What I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to set your username to an empty string. Looking at the [validation method](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/master/src/Core/UserValidator.cs#L58) within a GitHub repository of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity, there seems to be no way for you to allow `null` or an empty string as a valid username. Setting `AllowedUserNameCharacters` to `null` simply means that you're not checking for the whitelisted characters, which is also the default behavior, but pre-validation for `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` remains intact.

**Check the comment within this code snapshot from the official repository:**

```
private async Task ValidateUserName(UserManager<TUser> manager, TUser user, ICollection<IdentityError> errors)
{
    var userName = await manager.GetUserNameAsync(user);
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userName)) // <-- There is no way around this.
    {
        errors.Add(Describer.InvalidUserName(userName));
    }
    else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(manager.Options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters) &&
        userName.Any(c => !manager.Options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters.Contains(c)))
    {
        errors.Add(Describer.InvalidUserName(userName));
    }
    else
    {
        var owner = await manager.FindByNameAsync(userName);
        if (owner != null &&
            !string.Equals(await manager.GetUserIdAsync(owner), await manager.GetUserIdAsync(user)))
        {
            errors.Add(Describer.DuplicateUserName(userName));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
builder.Services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
{
  // Paswoord instellingen
  options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
  options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
  options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
  options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
  options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
  options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 1;

  // Gebruiker instellingen
  options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
  options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters =
    "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"; // here is the issue

  // Lockout instellingen
  options.Lockout = new LockoutOptions
  {
    AllowedForNewUsers = true,
    DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
    MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5
  };
});
```

Check the line where i've written the text that

> here is the issue

The characters you specify here are what the IUsersValidator uses for validating usernames. In my own case I had user names with @ and . characters - I had to add them here. Otherwise you do not get exceptions from this `AddUserToRoleAsync()` or `AddUserToRole()` with an invalid username, you only get a result with a status and an error message.

> Please configure the allowed username characters and you are good to go

Comment: Very useful example! Would have been difficult to know where to start reading the documentation to figure out that this is how to set the allowed characters. ("-._@+" are now included by default besides letters and numbers, by the way.)